# Making Google Chrome open Source Code in External Editor

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons, text-editors, source-code

How do I configure Google Chrome to open source files (.c or cpp) in an external editor either using EDITOR variable or `emacsclient` rather viewing them by itself.

Comment: What operating system are you using exactly?  Just set the default program for that extension to Google Chrome, of course, the file can't be modified in Google Chrome or any internet browser.